# How to do cross reference in systeme package?

Tags: systeme

In environments like `align` we use `\label{..}` commands before the line breaks `\\` for cross reference later.  How to use `\label{,,,}` commands in `systeme` package?  I could'nt make out how to do this in `systeme` from the example given in the documentation.

Comment: What number would `\ref` point to? `\systeme` doesn't number equations.

Comment: There's a possibility to number equations and refer them, but it doesn't use the standard way. See §1.11 Numérotation automatique, pp.6–8, in the documentation.

Comment: @Bernard The problem is that the method described numbers automatically all the equations after the  \sysautonum*{\hbox{ (**)}} command, whether I want it or not.