# How to align a system of numbered equations

Tags: amsmath, alignat

There are solutions to aligning a system unnumbered system of linear equations here:
[Aligning system of equations with zero coefficients](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493625/aligning-system-of-equations-with-zero-coefficients)
I want a similar solution to numbered system of linear equations.
I have also posted a question on using syteme for this here:
[How to do cross reference in systeme package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582053/how-to-do-cross-rerence-in-systeme-package)
However, I find the cross-reference in systeme too painful to use.
How to align a system of linear equations with other packages with the standard latex cross reference interface like alignat?

Comment: Do you need/want a curly bracket (or brace) to encompass the system of equations?

Comment: I don't want curly brackets.  I want the equations separately numbered so that I could use cross reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly straight forward to put a system of linear equations in an `alignat` if you consider the following basic setup:

- Each alignment point `&` has a `r`ight-`&`-`l`eft (or `r&l`) alignment structure;
- Keep variables, operators and relations in their own "column";
- Add `{}` around operators/relations to ensure proper spacing (as in `{}+{}`, `{}-{}` and `{}={}`);
- x variables requires x+1 alignment points (so, for 3 variables, you need `\begin{alignat}{4}`).

In the examples below I've marked the `r`ight-alignment point with numbers, which translates to the value used with `alignat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

% 3 variables ~ 4 alignment points
\begin{alignat}{4}
%  1         |  2         |  3         |  4
  2x & {}+{} &  y & {}-{} & 2z & {}={} &  3  \\
   x & {}-{} &  y & {}-{} &  z & {}={} &  0  \\
   x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} & 3z & {}={} & 12
\end{alignat}

% 3 variables ~ 4 alignment points
\begin{alignat}{4}
%  1         |  2         |  3         |  4
   x &       &    & {}+{} &  z & {}={} &  6  \\
     & {}-{} & 3y & {}+{} &  z & {}={} &  7  \\
  2x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} & 3z & {}={} & 15
\end{alignat}

% 4 variables ~ 5 alignment points
\begin{alignat}{5}
%   1         |  2         |  3         |  4         |  5
    x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} &  z & {}+{} &  w & {}={} & 13  \\
   2x & {}+{} & 3y &       &    & {}-{} &  w & {}={} & -1  \\
  -3x & {}+{} & 4y & {}-{} &  z & {}+{} & 2w & {}={} & 10  \\
    x & {}+{} & 2y & {}-{} &  z & {}+{} &  w & {}={} &  1
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

With the above structure in place, you can `\label`-`\ref` whatever you need in the usual way.